# Comparing values in two text files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to compare two text files in a specific manner. Every file contains thousands of line that look like this:

```
(29, '2 [484, 41, 69, 72]')
```

Where `29` is the `frame`, `2` is the `ID` and the four values inside the `[]` are the `rect` values which are `X,Y,W,H`. In this case, `X = 484, Y = 41, W = 69, H = 72`.

Every `frame` can have multiple `rects` attached to it. Anywhere from 1 to 20 or sometimes even more.

Here are examples of two files that i need to compare:

File A:

http://pastebin.com/qGLvxU1f

File B:

http://pastebin.com/1aKw6iuH

Now for the comparison method, i need to compare all of the `rects` on every `frame` using the following equation:

```
(overlap)/(two rects area - overlap) > Threshold
```

Where the Threshold is manually defined as 0.8 or so.

After I've determined which of the `frames` include `rects` in them that differ between the two files, i need to write to a 3rd file the `start frame` and `end frame` of every ID that (using the above mentioned equation) yielded a notable enough difference.

I am trying to compare line by line as so:

```
 def _compare(self, data1, data2):
        diff = []
        for frame in data1.keys():
            if frame in data2.keys():
                data1.pop(frame)
                data2.pop(frame)
        return diff
        with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join(diff))
```

But this only determines if a certain line has a difference and does not compare the actual values of each `rect`.

Comment: take a look at difflib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a class from these rectangles, so you could store the (x,y) values as offset, and (w,h) as size. Then you should add functions to these class, eg: toplef,topright,bottomlef,bottomright, wich computes the values you need.

eg:

```
    class rectangle:
def __init__(self,pos,size):
    self.pos=pos
    self.size=size
def topLeft(self):
    return self.pos
def topRight(self):
    return (self.pos[0]+self.size[0],self.pos[1])
def bottomLeft(self):
    return (self.pos[0],self.pos[1]+self.size[1])
def bottomRight(self):
    return (self.pos[0]+self.size[0],self.pos[1]+self.size[1])
def ares(self):
    return self.size[0]*self.size[1]
```

Computing the overlapping area is more tricky than i first thaught, but i found a solution, wich can be implemented relatively easily (But now i don't have time to implement it). The main idea is, you determines a third rectanle, wich contains both of the rectanles (its easy, you just have to find the minimal top left and maximal bottom right coordinates). Then you have to calculate the ara of the rectangles wich are remainings. Then you add the area of the four remained rectangles, the two initial rectangles, and if you substract the area of the big rectangle, you will get the area of the overlap. I know it's sounds complicated, but it's a general solution.

[image]

Comment: I edited the question so hopefully it is more clear now. Every file contains an incremental amount of frames usually 1-5000 or so. I need to be able to eventually write to a 3rd file, every set of frames that have a difference according to the mentioned equation. So for an example, one of the output files would simply be "ID:1 start frame: 20 end frame: 55".

Comment: can you possibly type an example of how you would create a class for the rectangles?